# Do import libraries work across dll versions?

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

Assuming that the function still exists, will import libraries still work with other versions of the dll? 
If not:

a) When will it break and what which parts will break

b) Is there any way to ensure it works across versions without `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an import library will work with different versions of the DLL. Of course, you won't be able to use it to call functions that exist in the DLL but are not defined in the import library (e.g. functions added in a newer version of the DLL).

Note that I am assuming that different versions of the DLL don't have modified function names and/or ordinals (whichever is used by the import library) or modified function signatures. In other words, I assume that the developer of the DLL is following the well accepted good practise for maintaining compatibility between DLL versions.

Comment: I found this "Explicit linking eliminates the need to link the application by using an import library. If changes in the DLL cause the export ordinals to change, applications that use explicit linking do not have to relink if they call GetProcAddress using the name of a function and not an ordinal value, whereas applications that use implicit linking must relink to the new import library." Which seem to contradict that.

Comment: @me' I'm working under the assumption that the import library is built using function names rather than ordinals, which is the standard approach.

Comment: How do you know/choose which one is used? (Import libraries or ordinals?)

Comment: You can use dumpbin to inspect the contents of the import library. Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-by-ordinal-rather-than-by-name?view=vs-2017